# I can't update an row

Tags: php, pdo

So the problem is I can't update an row. When I set the caption to be equal to a number it updates, but If I include the prepared statment it won't work...

Edit: Now it's not updating, but no errors.

```
<?php 
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db', 'root', '');
    $handler ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($_POST['submit'] == "Edit") {
        $sql = $handler->prepare('UPDATE images SET caption = :caption WHERE id = :id');
        $sql->execute(array(
                    ':caption' => $_POST['caption'],
                    ':id' => $_POST['id']
                ));
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<main>
    <form action="new.php" method="post">
        <?php
            $sql = $handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM images WHERE active = 1');
            $sql->execute();
            $row = $sql->fetchAll();

            for ($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++) {
                echo '<input type="text" name="id" value="'. $row[$i]['id'] .'"><br><br>';
                echo '<input type="text" name="caption" value="'. $row[$i]['caption'] .'"><br><br>';
            }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">
    </form>
</main>
```

Comment: Do you have PDO exceptions turned on? `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to make it throw a useful error. I notice that you don't have a `WHERE` clause on that `UPDATE`, meaning you are modifying _all rows_.

Comment: Yeah because I am having problem with id..Every time I set it up it says Undefined index...

Comment: So I updated my code, still no errors.

Comment: UPDATE needs a WHERE clause to work properly.

Comment: Now how do I remove this Notice: Undefined index

Comment: Which index is undefined? There should be more to the error message than just "undefined index".  I don't see an input in your form with `name='id'`, and that would certainly cause an undefined index when you use `$_POST['id']` since there is no such key in `$_POST`/.

Comment: Since you're fetching from DB, then change `':id' => $_POST['id']` to `':id' => $_GET['id']`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am still having undefined index.

Comment: Then you'll need to check if it's set using `isset()` for the fetched ID.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I have isset()

Comment: Did you try `':caption' => $_GET['caption'],
                    ':id' => $_GET['id']` or the answer below?

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple inputs with the same name, you will get only the last submited value !!
plus you are missing a closing tag:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++) {
   echo '<p><input type="text" name="caption['.$row[$i]['id'].']" value="'. $row[$i]['caption'] .'" /></p>';
}
```

After posting :

```
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Edit") {
try {  
  $handler->beginTransaction();
  foreach($_POST['caption'] as $id => $caption){
    $handler->prepare("UPDATE images SET caption=:caption WHERE id=:id");
    $handler->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $handler->bindValue(':caption', $caption, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $handler->execute();
  }
  $handler->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $handler->rollBack();
  echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
}
```